# Using java library how can we generate data like below in excel eg fastexcel

Tags: java

Using java library how can we generate data like below in excel
1-other data for node 1
-2-other data for node 2
-3-other data for node 3
-4-other data for node 4

Comment: private methods should be tested through testing the non-private methods that use it

Comment: This may be possible using reflection.

Comment: @Stultuske yes thats true but there was option in earlier version  ref- http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.com/2012/06/jmockit-tutoriallearn-it-today-with.html so similar i m looking in 1.48 as well

Comment: @dan1st do you have any reference handy?

Comment: It was only an idea but that seems to be what you want: [Mocking private method of class under test using JMockit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427685/mocking-private-method-of-class-under-test-using-jmockit) but look at the other answers, not only the accepted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private method mocking (using @Mocked) has been discontinued since JMockit 1.23, and will be restricted when using MockUp in version 1.27.